# Is it possible to have an agent that belongs to two or more containers with JADE?

Tags: java, agents-jade

Is it possible to have an agent that belongs to two or more containers with JADE?Is it possible to have an agent that belongs to two or more containers with JADE?

Comment: As i know, no. They can move on, but anyway each one can live in only one container.

Comment: thank you for the answer

Comment: @nikelyn do you have idea whether it is possible to exchange files between agents?  or communication is done only through ACL messages?

Comment: Only through ACL messages. If you have byte array as file you can use ACLMessage.setByteSequenceContent

Comment: @nikelyn thank you